# Calculation of probabilities in Naive Bayes in C#

Tags: c#, math, machine-learning, probability

I'm working on a Naive Bayes solution for C# where there are two possible outcomes. I have found a small sample code but was wondering if anyone would be able to explain the last line.

The analyzer is finding the probability a word belongs to 1 of two categories

`cat1count` is the number of words found in category 1 ( if the word is found 2 times in category 1 it would be 2 / total words in category 1)

`cat1total` = total number of words in category 1

as I understand it, `bw` is the probability the word is in category 1 and `gw` is the probability the word is in category 2

`pw` and `fw` are where I start to get a bit lost. The full source code can be found [here](http://github.com/joelmartinez/nBayes/blob/master/nBayes/Analyzer.cs).

```
        float bw = cat1count / cat1total;
        float gw = cat2count / cat2total;
        float pw = ((bw) / ((bw) + (gw)));
        float
            s = 1f,
            x = .5f,
            n = cat1count + cat2count;
        float fw = ((s * x) + (n * pw)) / (s + n);
```

what is `fw`? I understand what `bw`, `gw`, and `pw` are.

Comment: bw, fw, pw are variables which store values from cat1count, cat1total, you might want to post your source code, that would help more?

Comment: Not an answer but you might have a bug if the division `cat1count / cat1total` is a quotient of two `int` which was supposed to give a non-integral `float` result.

Comment: If you understand what `bw`, `gw`, `pw` are, please can you share that understanding so we don't have to work it out for ourselves?

Comment: sorry ill provide more information on this.

Comment: The analyzer is finding the probability a word belongs to 1 of two category's

cat1count is the number of words found in category 1 
( if the word is found 2 times in category 1 it would be 2 / total words in category 1)

cat1total = total number of words in category 1

as i understand it, bw is the probability the word is in category 1 and gw is the probability the word is in category 2

pw and fw are where i start to get a bit lost

the full source code can be found here

https://github.com/joelmartinez/nBayes/blob/master/nBayes/Analyzer.cs

Comment: @ricsh thankyou. Can you edit that into your question please (with the appropriate formatting)? You might get voted up for a complete well-formatted question, which will encourage more answers.

Comment: +1 for a better question. I have some idea of what's going on and will reply later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is called over and over again for each particular word `w` in the text (e.g. tweet) being analyzed. All the variables are conditional probabilities estimated using frequencies.

`bw` is the probability that the word `w` is seen given that the word is a category 1 text

`gw` is the probability that the word `w` is seen given that the word is a category 2 text

`pw` rescales the probability `bw` so that rarely seen words are on a similar scale to frequently seen words (mathematically, the division indicates that `pw` is a conditional probability)

`fw` simply shifts the scale so that `pw` can't be zero (or one). So if, for example, `pw=0` and `n=10`, `fw = ((1 * 0.5) + (10 * 0)) / (1 + 10) = 0.045`. (In general, a good way to understand this code is to play around with some different numbers and see what happens.)

In Naive Bayes, as you may know, the conditional probabilities are multiplied together (in this case via the `LogProbability` function in the [github Analyzer.cs file](http://github.com/joelmartinez/nBayes/blob/master/nBayes/Analyzer.cs) you pointed me at), so you're in trouble if you have a zero conditional probability anywhere in the multiplications, because the end result would be zero. So, it's common practice to substitute a small number instead of zero, which is the purpose of `fw`.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification, this is exactly what i wanted to know. perfect explanation, just one question, if pw was 0 would that indicate that the word w is not seen in either category, also would changing the numbers or 1 * 0.5 have any effect or just skew results.

Comment: @ricsh it's a pleasure, I learnt something doing it. When `pw=0` then also `bw=0` has to be true, i.e. the relative and absolute probabilities that the word is seen given that the word is in a category 1 text are both zero. Note: if the word is not seen in either category then `cat1total=cat2total=0` and you get a divide-by-zero exception when calculating `pw` (so, each word appears in at least one text). To get an idea what changing `s` and `x` does, the best thing to do is probably to try running the code with some different numbers. Changing them a bit probably wouldn't have a large effect.